# Is there a rippled Windows binary available for download?

Tags: ripple, windows, daemon

Is there a compiled Windows binary for the Ripple deamon rippled available for download? I only found its source code...

Comment: I don't believe there is, the majority that would want it would only trust building it themselves. The closest thing might be a [docker.io image](https://ripple.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5168) that _should_ be runnable under MSWindows. Depending on your exact needs you could ask on the [Ripple forums](https://ripple.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=2).

Comment: Can't someone share rippled installation guide for windows 64 bit please ?

Answer (score 1):

No, but there is a guide to building rippled on Windows: https://wiki.ripple.com/Visual_Studio_2013_Build_Instructions

Note this, though:

> We do not recommend Windows for rippled production use at this time. Currently, the Ubuntu platform has received the highest level of quality assurance, testing, and support.

That's probably why they don't offer a windows build - they want people to use Ubuntu. Perhaps you could use a VM - that's essentially what the Docker suggestion does anyway.